# Como transformar dados não digitais em dados digitais

Tags: arduino

Gostaria de saber como desenvolveria um software que exiba as estatísticas de um carro por exemplo. A velocidade não é um dado digital, até que eu transforme-a em um. Como fazer isso ? É utilizado microcontroladores, placas arduino (etc)? Como isto é feito?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Existe uma coisa chamada Conversão Analógica/Digital.

### **O que é Conversão Analógica/Digital?**

Trata-se de uma técnica que envolve a utilização de sensores, taxa de amostragem e cálculos matemáticos e um [Conversor A/D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q08S.jpg), para transformar uma grandeza analógica, como temperatura, pressão, velocidade (etc) em uma grandeza digital.

Internamente nos microcontroladores existe um componente importante chamado Comparador A/D ou [Conversor A/D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q08S.jpg). Ele é responsável por fazer a conversão de um nível de tensão (um valor analógico), para um valor digital. No caso do Arduino este valor varia entre 0 e 5v e o valor convertido possui uma resolução de 10bits.

### **O que é resolução?**

Com essas variações de níveis de tensão, um microcontrolador pode efetuar uma leitura e depois convertê-la para um valor digital, isso se dá pelos comparadores A/D, e depois que o microcontrolador efetua a leitura ela é comparada e convertida para que caiba em um número limitado de bits. A quantidade de bits é a resolução. Quanto maior a resolução, mais preciso é o valor comparado. O Arduino possui uma resolução de 10 bits, logo os valores analógicos lidos (0 a 5v) são convertidos em valores digitais de 0 a 1023 (2^10-1). Em um exemplo bem simples, temos que:

1. 0v corresponde a 0.
2. 5v corresponde a 1023.
3. 2,5v corresponde a 511.
4. 1,25v corresponde a 255

Depois que o valor é lido e convertido, o conteúdo desta leitura é armazenado em algum registrador do microcontrolador e você pode recuperar este valor mais tarde e utilizá-lo.

Em microcontroladores mais robustos, para uso em equipamentos médicos, por exemplo, a resolução dos Comparadores A/D costuma ser bastante alta. Já vi casos de 16 a 18 bits, um número altíssimo.

### **O que é taxa de amostragem?**

Segundo o [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxa_de_amostragem), taxa de amostragem é a quantidade de amostras de um sinal analógico coletadas em uma determinada unidade de tempo, para conversão em um sinal digital. Sendo uma frequência, é comumente medida em Hertz (Hz).

Amostras são os valores de um sinal analógico medidos em um determinado instante. O processo de captura das amostras é chamado amostragem de sinal.

Portanto, quanto maior o número de amostras do sinal, mais preciso ele será.

### **Teoria:**

Imagine o seguinte circuito:

[image: O CIRCUITO INTERNO DO CONVERSOR A/D]

Agora imagina que um sensor esteja conectado a entrada deste Conversor A/D. conforme o sensor varia  o nível de tensão, temos uma variação nos LEDs que serão acesos. Basicamente é isto, porém em um conversor A/D de 10 bits, temos 1024 combinações possíveis de leitura e, portanto, tudo isto é feito de uma forma bem mais sofisticada, utilizando filtros para ruídos e outras coisas que não cabem colocar aqui.

### **Software:**

Eis um exemplo simples de uma leitura analógica para Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  //Inicializa a comunicação serial com velocidade de 9600 bits por segundo
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Lê o valor do pino analógico A0 e armazena numa variável
  int valorLido = analogRead(A0);
  //Escreve o valor lido na serial
  Serial.println(valorLido);
  delay(1);   //Espera 1ms para a próxima leitura
}
```

### **Considerações Finais**

Portanto, caso você queira efetuar o valor da temperatura ambiente e utilize um sensor que varie 10mV a cada 1ºC, como é o caso do LM35. Você efetuaria a leitura do sinal analógico, que estaria entre 0 e 1023 e calcularia a temperatura correspondente como demonstrado a seguir:

> - 0~1023 = 1024 valores.
> - 0~5v = 500 valores (10mV cada)
> - 1v = 100 * 10mv
>
> logo:
>
> 500 <=> 1024 x <=> 1
>
> 1024x = 500
>
> x = 500/1024
>
> x= 0.0048828125 (Fator de conversão)
>
> Temperatura = (Valor Lido * Fator de conversão) * 100 Ou simplesmente:
>
> Temperatura = (Valor Lido * 0.48828125)

Desta forma, encontramos o valor da temperatura através do valor lido pelo sensor analógico, que varia sua saída em mV (milivolts). O Conversor A/D converte isto para um número de 10 bits (divididos em 2 bytes) que varia de 0~1023 e multiplicamos o valor obtido dos Conversores A/D pelo fator de conversão, que foi encontrado pela regra de 3x simples, resultando assim, na temperatura.

## **Fontes:**

1. http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxa_de_amostragem
2. http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversor_anal%C3%B3gico-digital
3. http://www.newtoncbraga.com.br/index.php/como-funciona/1508-conversores-ad
4. http://www.newtoncbraga.com.br/index.php/como-funciona/1509-conversores-ad-2.html
5. http://www.clubedohardware.com.br/artigos/1307
6. http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogReadSerial

Comment: +1 - Excelente resposta.

Comment: +1 Resposta sensacional.

Comment: Ótima resposta, bem completa