# Pegar uma variável do hardware e jogar em um software

Tags: arduino

Tenho um potenciômetro(hardware) que gera uma variável que oscilará de 0 à 1023. Preciso ler essa variável

```
void atualizaDados(){
  int valorpress;
  int valortemp;
  valortemp=analogRead(temperaturaPin);
  temperatura=valortemp/5;  
  pressao=analogRead(pressaoPin);
  for ( pressao=0; pressao>1024; pressao++) {
  //valorpress = analogRead(pressaoPin);
  //pressao=map(valorpress,0,50,0,40);
  Serial.println(pressao);  
  }
  vazao = analogRead(vazaoPin); 
}
```

O código que estava usando é este, a pressão está dando o valor 0 e não está oscilando.

Comment: Só uma correção no modo de ver a coisa, pra facilitar seu uso e entendimento da terminologia. O potenciômetro não gera uma "variável", tampouco a porta gera uma variável. Você tem uma função que retorna um valor (até aí não tem variável nenhuma no processo, no sentido de programação). Quando você faz `algumacoisa = função()`, está **atribuindo** o **valor** retornado à uma **variável**.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a condição do `for` (`pressao>1024`) é um erro ao digitar o código aqui, o valor da pressao está sendo impresso como 0, pois você depois de receber a leitura do Arduino, atribui o valor 0 para essa variável no loop `for`, veja:

```
    pressao=analogRead(pressaoPin);
    for (pressao=0; pressao>1024; pressao++) {}
```

De qualquer maneira, esse loop me parece desnecessário. Se você precisa apenas mostrar o valor da pressão dentro da faixa [0,1023], basta fazer isso:

```
pressao=analogRead(pressaoPin);
Serial.println(pressao);
```

Entretanto, é muito comum que se queira transformar o valor [0,1023] em pressão, o código abaixo é um exemplo de como fazer isso (para um sensor específico):

```
    //realiza a leitura na porta analica, o valor retornado já é o convertido pelo ADC  
    pressao=analogRead(pressaoPin);     

    //converte a leitura acima em tensão (considerando que a tensão de referencia são 5000 mv (ou 5 V).)
    float tensao = (pressao * 5000.0) / 1023.0;

    //transforma a tensão em pressão (kPa)
    float p1 = ((((tensao - 800.0)*100000.0) / 3200.0) / 1000.0);
```

Note que isso é para um sensor específico (código que retirei de um projeto antigo). Não vou entrar no mérito das constantes acima (nem me lembro pra te falar a verdade), o importante aqui é mostrar como transformar um valor lido numa porta analógica em um valor que faz sentido para o seu problema (seja pressão, temperatura, etc). Será necessário ler o datasheet do seu sensor para que a conversão acima seja feita.

Uma excelente reposta sobre conversão analógica digital ([ADC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9111/3084)).

Answer (score 0):

Nathalia,

posso estar nubando, mas acredito que o erro está no seu for loop.

```
for ( pressao=0; pressao>1024; pressao++) {
  //valorpress = analogRead(pressaoPin);
  //pressao=map(valorpress,0,50,0,40);
  Serial.println(pressao);  
}
```

você estrá atribuindo o valor 0 a variável `pressao` e depois disso está executando o for enquanto `pressao > 1024`. O que nunca acontece porque o valor de `pressao` é 0.

talvez você estivesse procurando isso:

```
for ( pressao=0; pressao < 1024; pressao++) {
  //valorpress = analogRead(pressaoPin);
  //pressao=map(valorpress,0,50,0,40);
  Serial.println(pressao);  
}
```