# Conversão valor analógico para digital Arduino

Tags: arduino

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um robô seguidor de linha o sensor que realiza a leitura é analógico (0 - 255) QTR Polulu, mas o projeto exige que seja usado valores digitais (0 - 1) nas comparações de valores como:

```
if(digitalRead(sensor1) > digitalRead(sensor2)){ ... }
```

Então como posso realizar a conversão de um valor analógico para digital? Seria possível realizar isso com PWM como:

```
#define pin = 13; //pino PWM
void setup() { ... }
int leitura = digitalRead(pin); //0 - 1
```

Muito Obrigado a todos desde já!

Comment: Correção sensor Pololu!

Comment: Respostas relacionadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9111/3084 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142023/3084

Answer (score 0):

Tentando clarear alguns conceitos sobre o primeiro `if`:
Ao se falar em digital, tem-se em mente somente os valores 0 e 1 lógicos, ou seja: booleanos **false** e **true**. Por isso, uma leitura digital ter um valor "maior" que outro só quer dizer que um está ligado e outro está desligado. Utilizar um operador de comparação matemática neste caso não "fecha" com o propósito: afinal, como comparar se um **true** é maior que um **false** ? (Claro que o compilador dá um jeito de resovler isso, mas para quem lê o código pode ficar meio estranho.

No caso de leituras analógicas, a função a ser utilizada é a `analogRead(PINO)`. Esta função retorna um valor de 0 a 1023, já que o conversor analógico digital do Arduino trabalha com 10 bits (portanto lembre-se de usar um *int* e não um *char*).
Agora, como converter os valores 0 a 1023 em "digital"? Você pode fazer diversas leituras analógicas e mandar pela serial para acompanhar no Serial Monitor. Com isso você vai saber qual a distância de corte/limite do seu sensor. Por exemplo: na distância que deseja-se medir, a leitura retorna em torno de 700 (às vezes 695, 697, 702, etc). Então pode-se considerar um valor lógico 1 (a presença de um objeto) as leituras abaixo de 710.

```
#define PINO 3
int valor = 0;
bool objetoPresente = false;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    valor = analogRead(PINO);
    Serial.println(valor); // manda o valor para a serial

    if (valor <= 710) {
        // objeto na frente do sensor a uma distância limite
        objetoPresente = true;
    }
    else {
        objetoPresente = false;
    }
}
```

Referência: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead

PS: nunca trabalhei com esse sensor QTR Pololu, mas googlando ele, ele tem uma bibliotea específica: https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J19/all e alguns vídeos no Youtube.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, então não há a necessidade de no if comparar daquele jeito posso fazer assim `if(objetoPresente){ } //se for true`

Comment: Na verdade, você nem precisa da variável `objetoPresente`, mas vocÊ precisa do `if (valor <= 710)`. Você pode executar o que precisa direto do if, substituindo o `objetoPresente = true` pelo tratamento se o objeto estiver na frente do sensor e no caso do `else` se o objeto não estiver na frente.